# Flutter SubItems in Menu Slider

Tags: flutter, dart, frameworks, native

Is there any way you can create sub items for a menu slider in flutter?

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer

In this example we have Item1 and Item2. How can I make sub items for item 1? To be more clearly, when I click on Item1 I want to exapand SubItem1, SubItem2, and when I click back on Item1, to hide the subitems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `ExpansionTile` within ListView. For example-

```
Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      ExpansionTile(
        title: Text("Some Title"),
        children: <Widget>[Text("Item 1"), Text("Item 2")],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

You could have a look at Expansion Panel List- [Link](https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/how-to-create-expansion-panel-list-in-flutter-2fba574366e8)

If this Answer help you, don't forget to upvote.